# Plot ROC curve from Cross-Validation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, roc

I'm using this code to oversample the original data using SMOTE and then training a random forest model with cross validation.

```
y = df.target
X = df.drop('target', axis=1)

imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(SMOTE(random_state=27,  sampling_strategy=1.0), 
                              RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state = 42))


f1_score = cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, X, y, scoring='f1_weighted', cv=5)
roc_auc_score = cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=5)

print("F1: %0.4f " % (f1_score.mean()))
print("ROC-AUC: %0.4f " % (roc_auc_score.mean()))

The output is : 
F1: 0.9336 
ROC-AUC: 0.6589
```

Now, my question is how to plot the ROC curve in this situation?

In the normal situation where we split the data into training and testing, I use this code:

```
y = df.target
X = df.drop('target', axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=27)

sm = SMOTE(random_state=27, sampling_strategy=1.0)
X_train, y_train = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

smote_rf =RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state = 42).fit(X_train, y_train)

smote_pred_rf = smote_rf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]

false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1, threshold1 = roc_curve(y_test, smote_pred_rf)
print('roc_auc_score for DecisionTree: ', roc_auc_score(y_test, smote_pred_rf))

# plot ROC

plt.figure()

auc_smote = auc(false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1)
plt.plot(false_positive_rate1, true_positive_rate1, color='red',lw = 1, label='SMOTE (auc= %0.5f)' % auc_smote)


plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], lw = 1, color='black',  linestyle='--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Abalone Data Set (RF)', fontweight='bold')
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this? If so would you mind posting the solution to your own question? Because I am having the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should run 1 cross-validation instead of a new cross-validation for every metric that you want. That is wasting resources and you are not measuring the same models for those metrics then.

For that, see the function `cross_validate` (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate)

Example:

```
>>> scores = cross_validate(lasso, X, y, cv=3,
...                         scoring=('r2', 'neg_mean_squared_error'),
...                         return_train_score=True)
>>> print(scores['test_neg_mean_squared_error'])
[-3635.5... -3573.3... -6114.7...]
>>> print(scores['train_r2'])
[0.28010158 0.39088426 0.22784852]
```

Specifically for the ROC curve, you probably need to go even more in detail and grab predictions from every round of your cross validation.
There is this example on the sklearn website that shows one way to do that: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc_crossval.html

Copy paste below:

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

# #############################################################################
# Data IO and generation

# Import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X, y = X[y != 2], y[y != 2]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape

# Add noisy features
random_state = np.random.RandomState(0)
X = np.c_[X, random_state.randn(n_samples, 200 * n_features)]

# #############################################################################
# Classification and ROC analysis

# Run classifier with cross-validation and plot ROC curves
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=6)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                     random_state=random_state)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (train, test) in enumerate(cv.split(X, y)):
    classifier.fit(X[train], y[train])
    viz = plot_roc_curve(classifier, X[test], y[test],
                         name='ROC fold {}'.format(i),
                         alpha=0.3, lw=1, ax=ax)
    interp_tpr = np.interp(mean_fpr, viz.fpr, viz.tpr)
    interp_tpr[0] = 0.0
    tprs.append(interp_tpr)
    aucs.append(viz.roc_auc)

ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
        label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
ax.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
        label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
        lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
ax.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

ax.set(xlim=[-0.05, 1.05], ylim=[-0.05, 1.05],
       title="Receiver operating characteristic example")
ax.legend(loc="lower right")
plt.show()
```

[image]